# Firebase - Querybase returning NULL for multiple values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Angular 1.5 and Firebase 3.6 and querybase.
In index.html -

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/querybase@0.6.0"></script>
```

Trying to query based on multiple values,  I am getting back NULL.
Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

In my controller -

```
 var ordersRef = firebaseref.child("orders");
 var querybaseRef = querybase.ref(ordersRef,['bookname', 'orderstatus']);
 var qdbref = querybaseRef.where({
                bookname: $scope.bookname,
                orderstatus: 'COMPLETED'
              });
 qdbref.on('value', function(snap) {
              var rdata = snap.val();
              console.log('snap :' + JSON.stringify(snap.val()));

         }, function(error) {
              console.error(error);
            });
```

My Database structure -

```
      {
        orders: {
             $orderid: {
                       bookname: "Master of the Game",
                       author: "Sydney Sheldon",
                       price: "6.99",
                       orderstatus: "COMPLETED"
                       }
                }
      }
```

Comment: @ Rosário Pereira Fernandes, Added DB structure.

Comment: @ Rosário Pereira Fernandes. It is working for a single criteria but not for multiple criteria. ex: const qdbref = querybaseRef.where({
                orderstatus: "COMPLETED"
                });